# Decimation modifier and face orientation

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking

I have a problem with a model on which I applied a decimate modifier. If I click on the "face orientation" button, I can see, that some of my polygons are inverted. Will it affect baking? If it will, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's easy.

Go into Edit Mode, select all of your mesh by pressing `A`, and press `Shift` + `N` to *Recalculate Normals*.